# Why we need a Hausdorff measure here?

Tags: lebesgue-measure, calculus-of-variations, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

If $\varphi\in \mathcal{C}^1_c(A)$ and $G\in \mathcal{C}^1(A,\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $\int_A \text{div} (\varphi G(x))\ dx=0$.  ($K$ is compact support)
[image]

Proof:

$I=\int_B \text{div} (\varphi \ G(x))\ dx=\int_{\partial B}\langle\varphi G(x),N_{\partial B}\rangle \ dH^{n-1}=\int_{\partial B}\varphi\langle G(x),N_{\partial B}\rangle \ dH^{n-1}=0$

I don't understand why we need a transition from Lebesgue measure to the Hausdorff one. Could you please explain? Thanks

Comment: Gauss' divergence theorem relates the 2d integral over $B$ to the one dimensional line integral. It seems some people like to express this with Haussdorff measures.

Comment: Thank you! Would it be wrong to continue to use Lebesgue measure in that case or there might some underwater stones?

Comment: The point is that $\int_B...\,dx$ is a two-dimensional integral, whilst $\int_{\partial B} ... dH^{1}$ is a *line* integral. 1d-Lebesgue, 1d-Riemann, Hausdorff one - does not really matter. I recommend to study Gauss' divergence theorem with a few simple examples where the line integral is ultimately an ordinary Riemann integral in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I notice that you are asking about $n$ dimension vs. $n-1$ dimension. Studying in $n=2$  should be enough to get the point.

Comment: Review the divergence theorem in three dimensions. You cannot write a surface integral as an integral with respect to Lebesgue measure in $\Bbb R^3$.